# Using NSManagedObject as data objects in UI

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've done simple demo app to illustrate a problem.

Assume I have Master - Detail application with the following context structure:

```
managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)

let detailVCContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
detailVCContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext

let deleteContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
deleteContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext
```

I use `detailVCContext` as a scratchpad for editing/undoing/saving data in details VC.

I use `deleteContext` as a context for deleting data (emulating push notification, that may need to delete some data).

Assume I pass `NSManagedObject` and `detailVCContext` to Detail ViewController where I show data from model and modify it. Right after opening DetailVC I delete this model from storage in `deleteContext`:

```
            let deletableID = object.objectID
            deleteContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in
                let itemInContext = deleteContext.objectWithID(deletableID)
                deleteContext.deleteObject(itemInContext)
                var error: NSError?
                deleteContext.save(&error)
                if (error != nil) {
                    abort()
                }

                deleteContext.parentContext?.save(&error)
                if (error != nil) {
                    abort()
                }
            })
```

This leads to accesing any property of model in Detail VC (or saving it) leads to

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a
>   fault for '0xd0000000000c0000
>   ''
>
> ---

Does it mean I cannot use NSManagedObject as a data model? Do I need to wrap it in other class?

*** UPDATE ***

Looks like I confused by my code.

All UI-related code in `DetailVC` works on `managedObjectContext` (I pass model object, fetched in managedObjectContext).

When I pass object to `DetailVC` I do:

```
if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
    if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
        label.text = detail.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
    }
}
```

When I press save button I do:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    detailItem?.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")
    let saveId = detailItem!.objectID
    detailVCContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
        let itemInContext = self.detailVCContext.objectWithID(saveId)

        var error: NSError?
        self.detailVCContext.save(&error)

        if let error = error  {
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the Ghostbusters taught you, don't cross the threads

The prime rule is that any attempt to carry an `NSManagedObject` across a thread boundary is unsafe. The most you can send is the `managedObjectID`

right here you pass the object across

```
deleteContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in
                let itemInContext = deleteContext.objectWithID(object.objectID)
```

so what you can do is

```
let deletableID = object.objectID

deleteContext.performBlock({ () -> Void in
                    let itemInContext = deleteContext.objectWithID(deletableID)
```

unrelated but also likely to cause you problems is this...

```
let detailVCContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
detailVCContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext
```

this context is no good for UI operations as all UI work must occur on the Main queue.

Comment: I've updated the code according to your suggestions, but it still has the same problem

Comment: Where is the object coming from in the first place. it's address doesn't look valid.

Comment: Yes, the reason address is invalid, because right after opening DetailVC I delete the object from storage

Comment: You seem to be describing wanting to use an object after you delete it?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to safily interact with deleted object (read it's property), but it seems it's impossible with CoreData?

Comment: You can't . That's what deleting means. Throw the record away, recover its system memory.

Answer (score 0):

You want a throw-away context as a scratchpad. User edits, if he *saves* you save the context, if he *cancels* you simply throw it away. I would follow this pattern:

- Before presenting the detail controller, create a new ad-hoc child context with `MainQueueConcurrencyType`.
- Fetch the object to be edited via `NSManagedObjectID` and pass it to the detail controller (e.g. in `prepareForSegue`). Also pass it the new context.
- Notify the parent controller if a save happened. It should also save its context and update the UI.